# Page will not scroll ionic css

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll

I am building a webpage using ionic css and everything is fine except the scroll does not scroll up or down.  I have tried removing

```
overflow:hidden;
```

elements but it doesnt make any difference and i can not see what is stopiing the pages from scrolling.

below is a link to my css page.

[Ionic Css](http://thinkecosolutions.co.uk/ionic.css)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put more code , but to solve the scroll problem you can add this :

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="y" style="width: 100%; height:400px;">

the content that you want to scroll 

</ion-scroll>
```

you can control the scrolled content scope with changing the height.